# Override minimize of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, minimize, windowlistener

I'm making a program with a logger. The logger has its own JFrame.
I'm trying to override the reaction from clicking on the minimize-button of that frame.
I would like the frame to either setVisible(false) or do the defaultCloseOperation (as i set that to hide earlier).

How should I do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @user545236, Applications should only have a single JFrame. Other helper windows should be dialogs. The accepted answer may work, but it is not the proper usage of a JFrame, that is why JDialogs exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a JDialog instead of a JFrame. JDialogs don't have a minimize button.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a WindowListener and add a [iconified handler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowIconified%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) that will react when the window is minimized.

Maybe:

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){

      public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e){
            frame.setVisible(false);
      }
});
```

Comment: treat the illness, don't doctor on symptoms ;-) Just to emphasize Rob's comment ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WindowStateListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowStateListener.html) like this

```
    f.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent arg0) {
            if (arg0.getNewState() == Frame.ICONIFIED) {
                // do stuff
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
 @Override
         public void windowIconified(WindowEvent event) 
         {
            //do your stuff
         }
 });
```

Comment: Your answer repeat existing answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5877604/1400768 with even less information or explanation.